# Is it necessary to add a username column in an app (using Devise,) in order to add that attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Many people say that you just have to add the `:username` attribute in the user model if you want to create a `:username` attribute:

**user.rb:**

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
```

I'm not sure if something like `:username` is already assigned in the database (just like you install Devise.)

If not, how can I add it to the database and what other things would I have to do?  (Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least for Devise 2.0 you need `username` in your database if you want to save it.

Create a migration - this will add a script to create the username field to your user table. Run the following from your terminal.

```
$ rails generate migration add_username_to_user username:string
```

run the migration (again from terminal)

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

After that your `user` table will have a `username` field added to it.

Then you'll need to edit the Devise views so users can register with a username. For that take a look at "Configure Views" section on the github [Devise page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

But basically, run the following to create the devise views (by default they're stored in the devise engine so you don't see them on disk)

```
$ rails generate devise:views
```

Then go in and edit the appropriate view file. For registration it's

```
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
```

You'll also want to show the username on their "edit" page. That's under

```
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
```

You'll need to add `current_user.username` somewhere on that "edit" view. But you'll get an error saying you can't access `username` so make it an accessible attribute

```
# User.rb - this is your user model
attr_accessible :username
```

You're lucky I just did this yesterday so I remember all the steps :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm very lucky. Hey but I'm having a problem in new.html.erb. I did this: `<div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.username_field :username %></div>` but I'm getting this error: `undefined method `username_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xae0b21c>`

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to do that. If i remember correctly, the default username column is named 'login'. To access that under username, you can just create a virtual attribute in the User class, like :

```
def username
  login
end
```

This would just return the login value as username.

You can find out more about virtual attributes here :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

EDIT:

Dty is right that this column is not there, so for detailed information on doing that :

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: Maybe that was an older version of Devise? As of Devise 2.0 there's no field named `login` in the table generated by Devise.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right, you can find detailed info here : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address